# How to shift my code in other block in Java?

Tags: java

When I run the whole program, the code always repeats in login activity and shows You do not have the account message in the loop. How do I move to createNewUser? I have attached the image of the code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqNp.png

Comment: It is recommended not to share image of the code but the Text of the code. Can you please upload text of the code? What if I or someone else wants to test and run your code? Uploading image doesn't help in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Call `createNewUser()` from `loginActivity ()`
Ask the user if they want to create a new account. If this is a console application, do something like this:

```
if(user != null)
    return user;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Do you want to create a new account(Y/N)?")
String input = sc.next();
if(input.toLowerCase().equals('y') 
    createNewUser();
return null;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call the desired method wherever you want and if it of another class then you need to create an object and then call the method, and if it is a static method then you can call it by class name only.

so here if the user is null then you need to call the CreateNewUser method.